# Analytical computation of an inverse function

Tags: inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

A function defined as $f(x,y)=0$ is said to be implicitly defined by the equation. The concept of inverting $f$ is closely related to the idea of solving the equation $y=f(x)$ for x as a function of y. Some form of localization is usually necessary to obtain an implicit function. Consider for instance the problem $S=\{(x,y)|x-y^2=0\}$.
The graph of S is not a function by itself, but it can have a neighborhood around the points $(x,y)$ where it becomes a function by itself. The linearization of $f$ at a particular point is used in the implicit function theorem for $f(x,y)=0$, which demands that $f$ be invertible by requesting that its Jacobian be nonsingular. For the problem I want to solve, I consider the continuously differentiable function:
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\frac{\log \left(c_3^2 y^2+c_3^2 y-c_1\right)}{2 c_3^2}-\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{c_3 (2 y+1)}{\sqrt{-c_3^2-4 c_1}}\right)}{c_3 \sqrt{-c_3^2-4 c_1}}-\frac{i x }{c_3}-c_2
\end{equation}
where $y=y(x)$, $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$, are constant values. As suggested by Tyma Gaidash, this equation can be rearranged as follows:
\begin{equation}
e^{2 \sqrt{c_{3}^2+4 c_1} (i x +c_2 c_{3})}=\frac{\left(c_{3}^2 y (y+1)-c_1\right){}^{\frac{\sqrt{c_{3}^2+4 c_1}}{c_{3}}} \left(2 c_{3} y+\sqrt{c_{3}^2+4 c_1}+c_{3}\right)}{\sqrt{c_{3}^2+4 c_1}-c_{3}-2 y c_{3}}
\end{equation}
I would like to explicit $y$ as a function of $x$. For $y \neq 0$, the Jacobian is non singular. Then the solution mapping $\{y|f(x,y)=0\}$
has a single-valued localization around $\bar{x}$ for  $\bar{y}$ which is continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $\bar{x}$.
The above equation can be rearranged as
\begin{equation}
x = -\frac{i \log \left(y^2 c_3^2+y c_3^2-c_1\right)}{2 c_3}-\frac{i  \text{ arctanh} \left(\frac{(2 y+1) c_3}{\sqrt{c_3^2+4 c_1}}\right)}{\sqrt{c_3^2+4 c_1}}+i c_2 c_3
\end{equation}
Now
\begin{equation}
x = y^{-1}\big(y(x)\big)
\end{equation}
Is it possible to use the inverse function theorem to compute $y(x)$ analytically?
If so, what conditions must be fulfilled for this theorem to apply?

Here is my idea.

Consider a function $g(y)$ of a complex variable $y$, holomorphic in a neighborhood of $y = 0$. Suppose $f(0)=0$ and $g^{'}(0) \neq  0$, so by the Inverse Function Theorem, $g(y)$ is one-to-one inside a small circle $C$ defined by $|y| = \epsilon$, and there is a unique inverse function $g(x)$ defined near $x = 0$ with $f(g(y)) = y$. Using the use of the Cauchy Residue Theorem and a new set of variables, $y = f(\zeta)$, $\zeta=g(y)$, and $d\zeta = g^{'}(y) dy$, we can obtain:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{f(C)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta -x} d\zeta=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{f(C)} \frac{g^{'}(y) y}{g(y)-x} dy
\end{equation}
So I can write
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{f(C)} \frac{\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} y}{f(x,y)} dy
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = \frac{y}{c_{3}^2 y (y+1)-c_1}
\end{equation}
The integral that results by substituting $f(x,y)$ and the partial derivative $ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ into the expression above is rather complex and I do not know how to calculate it. Unfortunately, I am rather rusty as far as calculating residuals is concerned (I have some memories from when I was a student). Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I know, but the point is that the problem I was trying to solve really involves finding the solution of a differential equation. After several attempts, I found a solution (it is the equation above), but in an implicit form. What I would like is to determine the solution in the form y=f(x). I think this is possible for holomorphic functions.

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $-i$ and subtracting the constant term gives: $-i x+h=\ln(y^2+ay+b)+c\text{tanh}^{-1}((2y-1)d)\implies e^{h-i x}=(y^2+ay+b)\left(-\frac2{2dy+d-1}-1\right)^\frac c2$ if it helps solve for $y$